# Help With Custom Appendix Header

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I have found a nice header for my appendix here in StackExchange. However, I have a problem. It numbers the chapter in my toc and I don't want that. This is my preamble:

```
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{apptools}
\makeatletter
 \def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill
 \kern \z@}
 \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \reset@font
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@
    \begin{flushright}
  \reset@font \scshape \bfseries \Huge\IfAppendix{Appendix}{} \thechapter \par
\end{flushright}
\hrule
\begin{flushright}
  \reset@font \LARGE \strut #1\strut \par
\end{flushright}
\vskip 15\p@
}}
 \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \reset@font
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@
    \begin{flushright}
      \reset@font \scshape \bfseries \Huge\vphantom{\thechapter} \par%
    \end{flushright}
    \hrule
    \begin{flushright}
      \reset@font \LARGE \strut #1\strut \par
    \end{flushright}
    \vskip 15\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

And this is how I write the appendix:

```
\begin{appendices} \appendixtrue

\chapter{Technical Manual: How to Operate the Microscope}\label{apx:f}
\input{appendix1.tex}

\end{appendices}
```

This is how the toc looks like:
[image]

Now, I have tried different stuff like renewcommand:

```
\begin{appendices}
\appendixtrue

\chapter*{Technical Manual: How to Operate the Microscope} % added an asterix
\label{apx:f}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Technical Manual: How to Operate the Microscope} % Add this line

\input{appendix1.tex}
\end{appendices}
```

but it didn't help. Do anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to provide a complete minimal example people can compile in order to see the problem. Code fragments are of little use.